# Symfony FosRestBundle: disable exception stack trace

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony6

I have a Symfony v6 application with FosRestBundle.

When I go to an endpoint which throw an exception, I got a page with the full error and the stack trace. Also in production mode.

[image]

The kernel is configured like this:

```
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
```

And this is the configuration of fos_rest I use:

```
fos_rest:
  body_listener: true
  body_converter:
    enabled: true
    validate: true
    validation_errors_argument: violations
  view:
    formats: { json: true, xml: false, rss: false }
    view_response_listener: true
  serializer:
    serialize_null: true
  format_listener:
    rules:
      - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json', prefer_extension: true }
      - { path: '^/publicapi', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json', prefer_extension: true }
      - { path: '^/', priorities: ['html'], fallback_format: 'html' }
  param_fetcher_listener: force
  exception:
    enabled: true
    codes:
      'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException': 401
      'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidArgumentException': 400
```

I do not found how to disable the stack trace in production environment.

Thanks for your help